# Snowflake zero copy clone billing

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

From snowflake document [clone storage usage](http://Because%20every%20table%20within%20a%20clone%20group%20has%20an%20independent%20life-cycle,%20ownership%20of%20the%20storage%20within%20these%20tables%20sometimes%20needs%20to%20be%20transferred%20to%20a%20different%20table%20within%20the%20clone%20group.%20For%20example,%20consider%20a%20clone%20group%20that%20consists%20of:%20%20Original%20table:%20%20Cloned%20to:%20%20Cloned%20to:%20%20T1%20%20%C2%BB%20%20T2%20%20%C2%BB%20%20T3%20%20If%20T2%20and%20T3%20share%20some%20micro-partitions%20and%20T2%20is%20dropped,%20then%20ownership%20of%20that%20storage%20must%20be%20transferred%20before%20T2%20enters%20Fail-safe.%20In%20Snowflake,%20this%20transfer%20occurs%20at%20the%20time%20the%20micro-partitions%20exit%20the%20Time%20Travel%20state%20and%20would%20otherwise%20enter%20Fail-safe.%20In%20the%20case%20above,%20the%20micro-partitions%20that%20were%20previously%20owned%20by%20T2%20are%20transferred%20to%20T3%20when%20the%20Time%20Travel%20retention%20period%20expires.).
Every table within a clone group has an independent life-cycle, ownership of the storage within these tables sometimes needs to be transferred to a different table within the clone group. For example, consider a clone group that consists of:

```
T1 >> T2 >> T3
```

`T1` has 10M data, `(p0=5M + p1=5M)`
`T1` and `T2` share 5M data `(Partition1 -> p1)`

`T2` has 15M data, `(p1 + p2=5M + p3=5M)`
`T2` and `T3` share 10M `(p1 + p2)` data

`T3` has 12M data, `(p1 + p2 + p4=2M)`
`T3` and `T2` share 10M data in total. `(p1 + p2)`

If the time-travel window is zero.
`T2` is dropped:

`p1` is still under `t1`'s ownership and referenced by `t3`?
`p2` ownership will be transferred from `t2` to `t3`?

And the total storage usage after `t2` is dropped is 
`p0 + p1 + p2 + p4 = 5 + 5 + 5 + 2 = 17`?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Update answer according to further research**

It does seem that micro-partition ownership does change ownership after the time-travel window (of 0 in this case) So I believe that you are correct

- p0 and p1 will still be owned by t1
- p2 and p4 will be owned by t3
- your storage math looks correct and should be 17

See [Owned Storage vs Referenced Storage](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-storage-considerations.html#owned-storage-vs-referenced-storage) documentation

---

**Related**: Storage metrics don't appear to change and will continue to point at the original table even if it gets dropped or renamed.
See [Table Storage Metrics usage notes](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/table_storage_metrics.html)

> Storage bytes are always owned by, and therefore billed to, the table
>   where the bytes were initially added. If the table is then cloned,
>   storage metrics for these initial bytes never transfer to the clones,
>   even if the bytes are deleted from the source table.

Comment: I think this contradicts the explanation at  [Owned Storage vs Referenced Storage](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-storage-considerations.html#owned-storage-vs-referenced-storage) which said that  the micro-partitions that were previously owned by T2 are transferred to T3 when the Time Travel retention period expires.

Comment: Excellent point. It's a little ambiguous, but my new understanding is that what I found is specific to storage metrics. And that the micro-partitions do actually change ownership.

Comment: In your answer, I guess there is a typo that p1 is owned by t3.